# Instance variables and a constructor?

Tags: java, variables, constructor, instance, palindrome

So I have my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeDriver
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  String another = "y";
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  PalindromeTester section = new PalindromeTester();
  while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
  {
  System.out.println("Enter a palindrome:");
  String str = scan.nextLine();
  if (section.palindromeTest(str))
    System.out.println(str + " IS a palindrome!");
  else
    System.out.println(str + " is NOT a palindrome!");
  System.out.println("Test another?(y/n)");
  another = scan.nextLine();
  }
 }
}
```

and...
import java.util.*;

```
public class PalindromeTester
{
public boolean palindromeTest(String str)
{
if (str.length() <= 1)
  return true;
if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(str.length() - 1))
  return palindromeTest(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));
  return false;
}
}
```

I was told that my code is good, but that i should have some more methods added into PalindromeTester, such as a constructor and a method that would store a potential palindrome into an instance variable, what would adding these methods do for my program if it already runs correctly?

Comment: No you don't need anything. But what I recommend is, whenever you use 'if' even though it has one line statement, use curly braces.

Comment: Also format you code better don't use one space. Just another way of doing this would be return str.equals(new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString());

Comment: Adding new line spaces between your if blocks also makes the code more readable, as well as proper tab spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, your PalindromeTester is a simple Utility class - it checks one string to be a palindrome or not. So one might argue if it's even worth putting that into a class - you could have that method in PalindromeDriver over all.

Let's for a second look at the suggestions:

**Have a constructor. Use an instance variable**

```
public class PalindromeTester {

  private String palindrome;

  public PalindromeTester(String candidate) {
    palindrome = candidate;
  }

}
```

Given this class, you could then convert your utility call `palindromeTest` into a slightly more appealing form:

```
  public boolean isPalindrome() {
    //Do check here
  }
```

And then think about additional methods like

```
  public String getForwards() { 
    //
  }

  public String getBackwards() {
    //
  }
```

All without the need to pass that string in once more.

**Bottomline**

What it would buy you? It would make your program more "Object oriented" and less "functional". And better to read maybe. And more extensible for the future.

Comment: Perfectly valid answer that you thought about, and it answers the user's question. I will counter-vote, unless the person provides a valid argument contrary to what I just wrote.

Comment: Thanks!(To everyone) you all answered my question and my understanding of object and utility classes is a lot better!

Comment: P.S the only reason I dont have everything in one class is because my prof will not allow it, their must always be a driver

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the only potential critique to your code as-written is that it is not actually *object oriented*, but still uses an instanced class.

The core principle of object orientation is the idea that the data used by a class and the stuff being done to that data should be bundled together in the same "scope", so that those two things can see each other, but nothing else in the program can see either except through a well-defined interface of "public" methods.

Honestly, were I writing this program, palindromeTest() would be static, the class would be final, and it would have a private constructor, turning it into a library rather than a class (think about functions like Math.random() -- you call random() without ever instancing a new Math() object).

However, I infer from your question that this is code written for an assignment. In that case, I would recommend considering a single instance of PalindromeTester as an object that tests only a single string, which is passed in to the constructor and stored in a private variable. This class would have a single public method that took no arguments, and returned whether the value in that private variable was a palindrome.

Comment: Thanks!(To everyone) you all answered my question and my understanding of object and utility classes is a lot better!

Answer (score 1):

I disagree in the sense that you have a very simple program written.

Probably what is happening is that the person wants you to have a more "Object-Oriented" structure to your program. But since your code is pretty simple and looks to just be solving a singular problem, making everything into objects in my opinion is not necessary in this case (even though you can do it).

**What would you gain?** By making your palindrome tester class more object-oriented, it can save the state of actions you perform with it (i.e. instance variables), encapsulate internal logic, and make it easier to share data across multiple instance methods (as is the general idea in OO).

But again, this is really just a matter of opinion, and the the most important point is, of course, that your code works correctly.

Comment: Same here :-) Downvoting without reason sucks.

Comment: Thanks!(To everyone) you all answered my question and my understanding of object and utility classes is a lot better!